# Select 5 items with caml beginning at the fifth row

Tags: 2010, client-object-model, jquery, csom, caml

I can get the 5 first items of a list with caml :

```
    var collListItemToBeUpdated = "";
    var listItemToBeUpdated = "";
    var enumerator;
    function getItemsToBeUpdated2() //this function called on button click to get ID's
    {
         var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
         var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Matériel Recyclage');
         var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
         camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View> <Query> <OrderBy> <FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='True' /> </OrderBy> </Query> <RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View> ");
         collListItemToBeUpdated = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
         clientContext.load(collListItemToBeUpdated);

         clientContext.executeQueryAsync(getItemsToBeUpdatedSuccess2, getItemsToBeUpdatedFailed2);
    }
    function getItemsToBeUpdatedSuccess2()
    {
        var i = 0;
         enumerator = collListItemToBeUpdated.getEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
             if(i>4)
             {

                    var oItem = enumerator.get_current();
                    var oListItem = oList.getItemById(oItem.get_id());
                    oListItem.set_item('Palette', '2');  
                    oListItem.update();
                    itemArray.push(oListItem);
                    clientContext.load(itemArray[itemArray.length-1]);
             }
             i++;
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(updateMultipleListItemsSuccess2, updateMultipleListItemsFailed2);
           }
         //updateMultipleListItems2();
    }
    function getItemsToBeUpdatedFailed2(sender, args)
    {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }

    function updateMultipleListItems2() //this function called on successfully getting ID's
    {   
        var itemArray = [];
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Matériel Recyclage');

         while(enumerator.moveNext())
         {
            var oItem = ListItemToBeUpdated.get_current();
            var oListItem = oList.getItemById(oItem.get_id());
            oListItem.set_item('Palette', '2');  
            oListItem.update();
            itemArray.push(oListItem);
            clientContext.load(itemArray[itemArray.length-1]);
         }  
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(updateMultipleListItemsSuccess2, updateMultipleListItemsFailed2);
    }
    function updateMultipleListItemsSuccess2() 
    {    
        alert('Items Updated');
    }

    function updateMultipleListItemsFailed2(sender, args) 
    {    
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```

But can you tell me how to get the five items after? I mean not 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 but 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. 
Something like RowBegin=5

I'm not looking for something based on ID, but based on the number of rows, something that can be used with my code.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SharePoint 2013 JSOM Paging - The Prev Page Button gives error - Request Failed.Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904 undefined](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153594/sharepoint-2013-jsom-paging-the-prev-page-button-gives-error-request-failed)

Comment: I looked the duplicate, and I don't understand why it would be a duplicated question. There is no answer for me

Comment: This url should help you  http://www.vrdmn.com/2012/08/paging-in-sharepoint-javascript-client.html Also on stack exchange similar query was answered : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144714/paging-sharepoint-list-using-csom

Comment: It's not the exact same question, but it provides you the material to achieve what you want...

Comment: And is there a way to put a specific position like that :  camlQuery.set_listItemCollectionPosition(6); So the caml update will happen starting from the item 6 ?

Comment: You need to work with combination of Rowlimit and ListItemCollectionposition properties.

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46375/caml-query-in-getlistitems-method-returns-no-rows-of-items?rq=1

Comment: I've updated my question : with this line, 5 lines will be selected, beginning with the sixth line? I've read this post http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69529/how-to-get-only-the-first-x-items-starting-at-position-y-from-a-list-using-caml But is it possible to write the position directly as I said?

Comment: I think Erin's answer is the best approach. Because set_pagingInfo takes a string, and that string needs to contain the last item id of the previous page. That would required to run a query to get that id then run another query with the paging info. (Paged=TRUE&p_ID=5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if it works for you.

You can avoid first five items using below mentioned `listitems.getEnumerator()` code.

```
    function getItemsToBeUpdated() //this function called on button click to get ID's
        {
             var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
             var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Matériel Recyclage');
             var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
             camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View> <Query> <OrderBy> <FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='True' /> </OrderBy> </Query> <RowLimit>5</RowLimit></View> ");

             collListItemToBeUpdated = oList.getItems(camlQuery);             
             clientContext.load(collListItemToBeUpdated);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

        }

function onQuerySucceeded() {
              var i = 0;
               var enumerator = collListItemToBeUpdated .getEnumerator();
                while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
                 if(i>4)
                 {
                         var item = enumerator.get_current().get_fieldValues();
                        console.log(item);
                 }
                 i++;
               }
            }
```

Comment: have you tried it? is this worked for you?

Comment: I'm trying to make it work

Comment: Good.. Please update here as well after it.

Comment: I've updated my question with your code added, and my whole code. But I have the following error with your part : The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed

Comment: Try this updated code.. & call failed method for as per your need.

Comment: call enumerator outside the main function as mentioned. The scope creates the problem for you.

Comment: I f you see my function getItemToBeUpdatedSuccess2, I have this line : ListItemToBeUpdated= collListItemToBeUpdated.getEnumerator();  Please tell me what I should do to make work your code in this function, because there is already one getEnumerator

Comment: updated your code... Please look into it...

Comment: With the last code (edited in question) I don't have any error, but the values aren't updated. I think it's because of the if(i>4), because we have i=0, so nothing is done. I don't know if you understand me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38862/discussion-between-hardik-and-jey10).

Answer (score 0):

I would grab the first 10 items, store them in an array, then return the last 5 items from the array.

Comment: that's a good idea, but it would be great to give me a way to begin working with array as you recommend

Comment: Actually, I think your enumeration with `i>4` ought to do the trick if you change your CAML row limit to 10. Or you could use your `itemArray`.

Comment: even with rowLimit=10, I have no error, but nothing is updated now. I think the "if" is close to do the work, but it doesn't place the item at the row 10

Comment: To troubleshoot, will you try `console.log(i)` to make sure it's running all the way up to 9?